# Guardar y obtener objetos en Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

soy nuevo en kotlin y quiero guardar un objeto en un activity y poder obtenerlo en cualquier otro activity, esto en java lo hago con una clase repositorio,ahí guardo y obtengo el objeto entero,quisiera saber si hay forma de hacer lo mismo en kotlin.
Dejo el código de como lo hago en java,gracias.

Mi clase repositorio:

```
public class UserRepository {

private static UserRepository sUserRepository;
private Context mContext;
private User user;
private List<User> mUserList;

private UserRepository(Context context){
    mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
}

public static  UserRepository get(Context context){
    if (sUserRepository == null){
        sUserRepository = new UserRepository(context);
    }
    return  sUserRepository;
}

public Context getContext() {
    return mContext;
}

public void setContext(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public List<User> getmUserList() {
    return mUserList;
}

public void setmUserList(List<User> mUserList) {
    this.mUserList = mUserList;
}
```

Obtengo el objeto User en la respuesta de un endPoint y lo guardo llamando a la clase repositorio:

```
 private void attemptLogin() {

    if (NetworkUtils.isNetworkAvailable(this)){

        //Get data
        mEmail = mUserEditText.getText().toString();
        mPassword = mPasswordEditText.getText().toString();

        if (!mEmail.isEmpty() && !mPassword.isEmpty()){
            hideLoginButton(true);
            LoginCredentials credentials = new LoginCredentials();
            credentials.setUserName(mEmail);
            credentials.setPassword(mPassword);
            rocontVentasApi.login(credentials)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new DisposableSingleObserver<Response<LoginResponse>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Response<LoginResponse> loginResponse) {
                    hideLoginButton(false);
                    if (loginResponse.isSuccessful()){
                        String token= null;
                        if (loginResponse.body() !=null){
                            token = loginResponse.body().getToken();
                            setToken(token);
                            //Save the user object for later use
                            UserRepository.get(getApplicationContext()).setUser(loginResponse.body().getUser());                                                                startDashBoardActivity();
                        }
                    }else {
                        AlertUtils.snack(view,getString(R.string.error_start_login));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    AlertUtils.snack(view,getString(R.string.error_ocurred_text));
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    hideLoginButton(false);
                }
            });
        }else {
            AlertUtils.snack(view,getString(R.string.error_empty_login));
        }
    }else {
        AlertUtils.snack(view,getString(R.string.error_no_internet_connection));
    }
}
```

Obtengo el objeto User llamando a mi clase repositorio:

User mUser = UserRepository.get(getApplicationContext()).getUser();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En Kotlin puedes crear un objeto sin necesidad de los set y get que se requieren el java, en la propia activity puedes crear (fuera de cualquier funcion)

```
// Ejemplo de usuario, tu puedes crear o modificar tus variables segun lo requieras    
data class userRepository (val context : Context, val user_name : String, val user_age : Int)
```

Para crear un objeto con esos datos

```
val mUser = userRepository(this, "Mario", 30)
```

Accedes a cualquier dato de la siguiente forma

```
val nombre = mUser.user_name
val edad = mUser.user_age
```

y si quieres acceder a ese usuario (objeto) desde cualquier otra activity una muy buena opcion es crear la variable **mUser** dentro de un companion object, [aqui explico como lo puedes hacer facilmente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/265382/48809), recuerda que si vas a modificar alguna variable debes asignarla como var.

Comment: Lo implementare,saludos