# Cómo pasar informacion de un Activity --> BottomSheetDialogFragment --> Activity?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment, kotlin

soy nueva en Kotlin, en mi MainActivity tengo un ListView, cuando se presiona un Item, se envía la posición de ese item (Int) al Fragment, hasta ahí no tengo problema, lo recibe bien, en ese Fragment hay dos botones, cuando presiono cualquiera hace un Intent, en cualquiera de los dos necesito mandarle ese dato Int (posicion del item antes presionado) a esa Activity que mando llamar en el Intent, lo intente a través de un putExtra, pero cuando quiero usar el dato en el segundo Activity, me da null

Dejo el código para apoyo

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), opcionesSheetEx.BottomListener{
    override fun redirigir(ruta: Int) {

    }



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val adapter= RutasAdapter(mContext= this, listaRutas = listaRutas)
        listViewRutas.adapter=adapter
        listViewRutas.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            val fragmentoOpciones = opcionesSheetEx()
            fragmentoOpciones.setPosition(position);
            fragmentoOpciones.show(supportFragmentManager, "opcionesSheetEx")

        }
    }

}
```

ESTE ES MI FRAGMENT

```
class opcionesSheetEx : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    private var mBottomSheetListener:BottomListener?=null

    private var posicion: Int = -1

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_opciones_sheet_ex, container, false)
        val bundle : Bundle= Bundle()

        val intent: Intent = Intent(this.context,mapasVista::class.java)
        v.registroTextView.setOnClickListener {

            Toast.makeText(v.context, "Posicion a redireccionar: "+posicion.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            dismiss()
        }
        v.mapaTextView.setOnClickListener {

            startActivity(intent)
            intent.putExtra("ruta",posicion.toString())
            dismiss()
        }
        return v
    }
        interface BottomListener
        {
        fun redirigir(ruta: Int)

        }
    public fun setPosition(position:Int)
    {
         mBottomSheetListener?.redirigir(position);
    }

    public fun getPosition(position:Int): Int {
        return this.posicion;
    }
    override fun onAttach(context:Context?)
    {
        super.onAttach(context)
        try {

             mBottomSheetListener= context as BottomListener?
        }
        catch(e: ClassCastException)
        {
            throw ClassCastException(context!!.toString())
        }
    }

}
```

Este es el onCreate de mi segundo Activity

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapas_vista)
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

        val ruta= intent.getStringExtra("rutaselec")
        Toast.makeText(this,"Seleccionaste"+ruta,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
//AQUI IMPRIME NULL
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crea una variable global dentro de un [companion object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/objects-and-companion-objects.html) (puede ser en la primera activity) y que si en algún momento otra activity la necesite ya se le haya pasado el valor desde tu listview, por cierto es recomendable utilizar [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) ya que es mas optimo que los ListView para cualquier dispositivo.

En tu primera activity

```
companion object {

    /*
    * EN ESTA VARIABLE SE GUARDARA LO QUE NECESITES
    */  
    var m_pos = 0

}
```

Donde necesites reasignar ese valor simplemente puedes hacer

```
listViewRutas.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
        //val fragmentoOpciones = opcionesSheetEx()
        //fragmentoOpciones.setPosition(position);
        //fragmentoOpciones.show(supportFragmentManager, "opcionesSheetEx")
        m_pos = position

    }
```

Tu segunda activity para obtener ese dato

```
    /*
    * PARA EFECTOS DEL EJEMPLO LLAMO TU PRIMERA ACTIVITY COMO ACTIVITY_MAIN
    * TU DEBES COLOCAR EL NOMBRE DE LA ACITIVY DONDE ESTAS COLOCANDO EL COMPANION OBJECT
    */

    var pos = ACTIVITY_MAIN.m_pos
```

Ahora pos tendra el valor que asignaste en MAIN ACTIVITY

Comment: Gracias Leonardo

Comment: Es un gusto Nancy, veo que eres nueva por aquí, si te ha funcionado el código que coloque puedes marcar la respuesta como **correcta** y te recomiendo ver [Como funciona stackoverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Bienvenida